# C# How to store a float and read it in a function

Tags: c#, function, floating-point

I'm very new to programming and I know this is simple answer but I for the life of me can't figure it out.

```
    public float getCurrentY()
    {
        float CurrentY = API.Extension.ReadFloat(Variables.CIT_PLAYER_Y_COORD);
        return CurrentY;
    }
```

When I toggle box is checked it gets the current Y

```
    private void CITFlightTestToggle_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CITFlightTestToggle.Checked == true)
            {

            getCurrentY();
            }

            else if (CITFlightTestToggle.Checked == false)
            {

            }
    }
```

I basically want the value of the current why at the time of when the player checks the toggle box and then add a value from a trackbar onto that stored value. The problem is it keeps getting the currentY when you move the trackbar and the current Y keeps changing since I am adding to it.

```
        private void CITFlyingHeightTrackBar_Scroll_1(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
        float diviedflyingheight = CITFlyingHeightTrackBar.Value / 10f;
        float current_num = getCurrentY();
        float flyingheightadded = current_num + diviedflyingheight;
        if (CITFlightTestToggle.Checked == true)


            if (levelchecktext == Variables.CIT_LVL_GREAT_CLOCK_A)
            {

                API.Extension.WriteFloat(Variables.CIT_GCA_Y_COORD, (flyingheightadded));
            }
            else
            {
            }
         }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: A "get" type call should probably be a function.  CurrentY sounds like it shouldn't be a string.  `public float GetCurrentY()` is probably how it should be written, and have it return the value.  Get rid of the CITCurrentYString since you only have it local to that method, so you never get to use the value.

Answer (score 4):

welcome to stack overflow

you see that word "void" in your method declaration? That's the return type. You change that to string, and then use the "return" keyword to select the value it returns.

```
public string getCurrentY()
{
    string CITCurrentYString = null;
    float CurrentY =  API.Extension.ReadFloat(Variables.CIT_PLAYER_Y_COORD);
    CITCurrentYString = (CurrentY.ToString());
    return CITCurrentYString;
}
```

Is there a reason you are converting to a string though? It looks like you really need a float. Like this

```
public float getCurrentY()
{
    float CurrentY =  API.Extension.ReadFloat(Variables.CIT_PLAYER_Y_COORD);
    return CurrentY;
}

private void CITFlyingHeightTrackBar_Scroll_1(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    float current_num = getCurrentY();
}
```

Comment: even shorter, `float current_num = API.Extension.ReadFloat(Variables.CIT_PLAYER_Y_COORD);`, assuming API is a namespace or static class

Comment: yup, I saw that, but since this was the OPs first question, I figured answering the "how do I return a value" question was more important

Comment: Thanks for the help. the problem is I dont want currentY to be written everytime the trackbar is moved. I bascially want that float to be stored and then the trackbar value added onto it. originally i created a label made it invisible and just converted the float to text and parsed it and that's how i stored the value (you select a checkbox and then it calls the getCurrentY) but I figured there must be a better way

Comment: aha, looks like we have an XY problem here. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem  

Where are you actually using this value?

Comment: I updated my original code to show it. XY problem is exactly what I have now I'm attempting to learn the proper way lol